# How to use different comment string for yaml blocks inside markdown files?

Tags: comments, filetype-markdown, plugin-vim-commentary, filetype-yaml

Many markdown implementations allow for a leading yaml configuration block like so:

```
---
title: "My title"
date: 2023-12-29
---

## Heading

Some markdown text
```

With the vim commentary plugin, I can setup vim to use html comment strings (`<!-- %s -->` ) for the markdown file, but I can't figure out how to automatically switch to a leading `#` when commenting in the yaml code block. I tried https://github.com/suy/vim-context-commentstring but could not get it to work for this scenario.

Comment: Well, there is nothing built-in for that so you need a third-party plugin. You appear to have found one that claims to do what you want, so now it is up to you and the plugin maintainer to move things forward. If you can't make $PLUGIN work, then use its issue tracker.

Comment: Thanks @romainl, Interestingly it seems to work even without that plugin for a "quarto" filetype (another markdown format), but not for the "markdown" or "pandoc" file types. I'll try to see if I can figure out if that is related to some other plugin or setting I have